# PDF not displaying properly in built in viewer of FireFox

Tags: html, firefox, pdf

I have a pdf uploaded in my website , the words display 100% fine in Chrome and IE , how ever in Firefox few of the words display like webding font. Helvetica is the font used for entire pdf , but out of all the document only 2 words are displayed in webding type font i.e distorted or incorrect.
I have updated the pdf.js file via installing add on , but its still like that.
My firefox version is 32.0.3. Rest all the pdfs are displayed 100% fine , what can be the problem with this one?

Comment: Without the PDF in question, people can merely guess.

Comment: people can merely guess what?

Comment: *people can merely guess what* - what the problem can be with the PDF in question.

Comment: "not displaying properly" is i guess enough to let the knowledgeable person know what the issue is

Comment: Then I guess there are not many *knowledgeable persons* around.

Comment: i would've been better if you had focused on the problem , could've helped me and many out there like me.... never mind....